# Electric field of uniformly charged plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

Which are the null components (in a Cartesian coordinate system) of the Electric field of uniformly charged plane in $x=0$?

I consider the coordinates : $(x,y,z)$

I think that $E_x = 0$, $E_y \ne 0$, $E_z = 0$

Is it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange Elsa.  Please note that this is not a homework help website.  We do not check your work.  That is your teacher's job.   http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming y is perpendicular to the plane, you are correct, by symmetry you cannot have a preferred direction along the plane, so the electric field components
 must be zero

Answer (score 0):

The plane is an equipotential surface. Since the electric field is the (negative) gradient of the potential, the electric field can have no non-zero component parallel to the surface.